# Where can I get statistics about illness relationships with vitamins and minerals deficiency?

Tags: data-request, medical

I would like to know where I can get a credible source of information about health.
I read a lot of information about what causing an illness a lot of information that somebody else claim its wrong, I am a computer scientist and I know how to get info from data, so I want a data set contains illnesses and and what is the diagnosis, or illness and what deficiencies in the Patients.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to search for diseases and their symptoms.
You can obtains such a data set from [here](http://kaggle.com/data/55703).

Answer (score 0):

Check Journals for Sports Medicine, and for Professional Athletics.

If you want a diagnosis app, check https://ada.com/, free for Android and Apple.

Another possibility is to search [OpenClinicalTrials on PubMed](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=mineral+deficiency&filter=articleattr.data&filter=pubt.clinicaltrial) . However, finding an article there that has also  results/datasets attached is possible but can be time consuming. These results are for doctors and epidemiologists.

Scroll down to "Associated data", then click on the link to clinicaltrials.gov. [Example](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/record/NCT02694978) , click on "Study Results".